# set heartbeat property on rabbitmq autoconfig connectionfactory bean

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-rabbit

How should I set the heartbeat property on a CachingConnectionFactory bean in rabbitmq spring?
This is in a cloud foundry environment. So the application will be using a service binding via manifest file and I don't have the broker host name.
In my `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean, I make use of the CachingConnectionFactory bean and I guess it's autowired by Spring.

I could do in there,

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    ...
}
```

since I am not creating a bean for CachingconnectionFactory, I don't have a place for assigning that property, this is the only place I see for it.

Is there any other way to assign this property on ConnectionFactory in auto-configured setting?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Spring Boot Properties Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

```
spring.rabbitmq.requested-heartbeat= # Requested heartbeat timeout, in seconds; zero for none.
```