# New master not selected automatically in queue mirroring

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want to configure mirrored queues in my applications so that if any node is down, it can survive failure and reconnect to the mirrored nodes.

Mirroring of queues is done. And i have added ip address and port in application.properties file to get connection on failures.

application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=172.20.97.39:48442,172.20.97.144:57037,127.0.0.1:3962
```

When i stop the master node, i expect the queuing to continue on other nodes. What is happening right now is i am getting failed message stating not able to enqueue.

Can someone please help me to know are there other code related changes i'll have to do to configure mirrored queues or something which i am missing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have done when you state "Mirroring of queues is done"?

Comment: Created a cluster with 3 nodes. Added ha policies and instructions as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html document.

Comment: And you saw the +1 (or +X) next to the queue in the admin console (or confirmed completion of the replication another way)?

Comment: Yes. it has +2 in nodes column. When the node is up and I enqueue, it gets replicated in all the nodes. So mirroring is completed i guess.\

Comment: Sorry for the litany of questions, but necessary for trying to help out troubleshooting. Could you indicate how you validated that the "not able to enqueue" relates to the use of a connection to a working node? if you're using the admin console from a working node to publish to the exchange, do you have the same error?

Comment: No worries. What i did was from my application, i hit an api which enqueues data after some operations. When i enqueue while all the node are open, I get successful response. But when hitting the api while master node is closed, i get error stating "Error enqueuing the data." (This is error given by me whenever enqueuing fails).

Comment: From what you describe, it feels more like the producer application hasn't detected that its connection to rabbitmq has failed. Could you try to set the `spring.rabbitmq.requested-heartbeat` property? from what I could read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#_reference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118570/set-heartbeat-property-on-rabbitmq-autoconfig-connectionfactory-bean) this could help in the failure detection